# whats wrong with this for loop?

Tags: php

Can someone please help me fix this code up? I am getting some weird error:
this for loop not working properly

```
<?php 
$languages=array('te','hi');
for($langIndex=0;$langIndex<count($languages);$langIndex++)
{
echo $languages;} 
?>
```

expected result:

```
te,hi
```

actual result:

```
Array Array
```

Comment: <?php 
$languages =array('te','hi');
for($langIndex = 0; $langIndex<count($languages) ;$langIndex++)
{
echo $languages;
}

?>

Comment: thnks to duskwuff for editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to get the array-entry for the iteration first (`$languages[$langIndex]`):

```
for($langIndex=0;$langIndex<count($languages);$langIndex++) {
  $language = $languages[$langIndex];
  echo $language;
}
```

another possibility would be to use a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop:

```
foreach($languages as $langIndex => $language) {
  echo $language;
}
```

Comment: perhaps `echo $language` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out the whole `$languages` array each time around the loop -- there's nothing inside the loop which actually looks at what value `$langIndex` has. You could either print out the string at the index you're currently looking at:

```
echo $languages[$langIndex];
```

Or you could save yourself some trouble and use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($languages as $lang) {
    echo $lang;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use array index when addressing to elements of array

```
<?php 
$languages=array('te','hi');
for($langIndex=0;$langIndex<count($languages);$langIndex++)
{ 
    echo $languages[$langIndex];
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally use `echo array`. Try this:

```
<?php 
$languages=array('te','hi');
for($langIndex=0;$langIndex<count($languages);$langIndex++)
{
    echo $languages[$langIndex];
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your array ($languages) every time, in your loop...

try with :

```
for($langIndex=0;$langIndex<count($languages);$langIndex++)
    echo languages[$langIndex];
}
```

or

```
foreach($languages as $langue){
    echo $langue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the desired result `te,hi` from that array, use

```
echo  implode(',', $languages);
```

Answer (score 0):

and for performacne reason!

```
<?php 
$languages=array('te','hi');
for($langIndex = 0, $count = count($languages) ;$langIndex < $count; $langIndex++)
{
    echo $languages[$langIndex];
} 
?>
```